# Plot is passing a bizarrely shifted x_min value to the user-specified Ticks function

Tags: plotting, function-construction, functional-style, ticks

The [documentation for Mathematica's `Ticks` option](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) says that you can specify the ticks for an axis by passing a function rather than a plain list description. The function is expected to take the arguments $x_{min}, x_{max}$ and return a specification for the ticks.

So I thought I'd run, say,

```
Plot[1 - Cos[x*Pi], {x, 0, 10}, 
 Ticks -> {Range[#1, #2, 2] &, Automatic}]
```

to produce a graph with ticks at 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, corresponding with the zeroes of the plotted function. That doesn't happen, though. I get this:

[image]

The $x$-axis ticks, including their labeled offsets, are consistently shifted to the left by 0.20833 units.

(When I manually specify `Ticks` as `{{0,2,4,6,8,10}, Automatic}` – which is what I assumed the expression would reduce to after function application – then the output *does* correctly place the ticks at those integer offsets. So the shifting behavior only has to do with calling the passed-in function.)

It seemed as though the anonymous function `Range[#1, #2, 2] &` might have been receiving the wrong input value of $x_{min}$. That suspicion was confirmed when I tried

```
Plot[1 - Cos[x*Pi], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {Print[#1] &, Automatic}]
```

and it printed -0.208333 instead of 0!

The printed output doesn't change if I give `Plot` a different function to graph, but it does depend on the $x$ domain. Specifically, `Plot` is feeding the `Ticks` function a value of $x_{min}$ which is actually $x_{min} - 0.0208\overline{3}(x_{max} - x_{min})$.

Have I accidentally triggered some weird setting that modifies arguments as they get passed to a callback function? What gives?

I'm running Mathematica 11.2 on macOS 10.4.6. This doesn't appear to happen when I evaluate the same inputs in Wolfram Cloud.

Comment: no problem in V12 on windows. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T2Edg.png)

Comment: Are you sure the functional representation works as expected?  I tried this and it seems to do what you want: 
Plot[1 - Cos[x*Pi], {x, 0, 10}, Ticks -> {Range[0, 10, 2], Automatic}]

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem doesn't lie with the anonymous function itself. If I evaluate the bare expression `Range[#1, #2, 2]&[0, 10]`, it yields (as you'd expect) the same thing as `Range[0, 10, 2]`. The problem only arises when I pass that anonymous function – or _any_ function, anonymous or named – to `Ticks`.

The trig function I used in the post was a somewhat artificial example; I'd like this feature to work so I can automatically place ticks at intervals that depend on the x domain in a more complex way. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Lambdas to the rescue: I sidestepped the problem by wrapping the whole thing in another functional layer. Say `f` is the function I'm plotting, and `t` is the function that maps (x_min, x_max) to your desired tick offsets. Then you can just write `Plot[f, {x, #1, #2}, Ticks -> {t[#1, #2], Automatic}]&[0, 10]`, and the specification gets computed and expanded before being passed into `Ticks`. I still really want to know what's sending messed-up arguments to my callback functions, though, in case it manifests elsewhere.

Comment: Great  that you solved this.  Would you please provide an example of  "f" and "t" to show how it works?  Thanks in advance.